# Django, How to filter data with 2-layers foreign key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am confused with how to get the right result...

Here is model

```
class StockInForm(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, ...)

class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(...)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, ...)

class Supplier(models.Model):
    supplier = models.CharField(...)
```

I were given a supplier keyword and what I want to get is the form which match the keyword. I have try many times but don't know how to do it. May I have some tips? Thank you.

---

If I was given a color keyword, I can use

```
StockInForm.objects.filter(**{"color__color" : keyword})
```

to get all the form with color keyword. But it doesn't working when I use like this

```
StockInForm.objects.filter(**{"color__color__supplier " : keyword})
```

Comment: Instead of color__color__supplier, make it color__supplier__supplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do

```
StockInForm.objects.filter(color__supplier__supplier=keyword)
```

Or if you want to use dictionary:

```
StockInForm.objects.filter(**{"color__supplier__supplier " : keyword})
```

`color__supplier__supplier` - you check *color* field of `StockInForm`. It relates to `Color`. In `Color` check *supplier* field. Which relates to `Supplier` model and last one is check *supplier* field.